# How to Find a Time value (anything like #:##) in a string

Tags: regex, vb.net

Looking for a way to find anything that looks like a time value, such as 1:00 or 2:30 anywhere in a given string.  I'd rather not scan the whole string for

```
If String.Mid(myString,i,4) Like "#:##" Then ...
```

if there is a better way to accomplish the same thing.

An occassional false positive is okay, so if I get `0:99` identified as a time value, there is no harm in that, and finding the `2:00` part of the time value `12:00` is fine too -- pointing at the character `2` instead of the character `1` causes no problems. And for this application, finding other separators besides the colon isn't needed.

Is a RegEx the best way to search for this sort of pattern, or is another approach more efficient?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A RegEx is probably the most straightforward solution for what you described.

```
Dim stringToMatch = "The time is 1:00 or maybe 13:01 or possibly 27:03 or 4:99 or part of 103:17, but not 22:7"
Dim matcher = New Regex("[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}")
Dim matches = matcher.Matches(stringToMatch)
For Each match As Match In matches
    Console.WriteLine("Found match {0} at position {1}", match.Value, match.Index)
Next match
```

From there, it's simple to alter the RegEx pattern to better suit your needs, or to examine the Match objects to determine what was matched, at what index in the original string.